# Python version of PHP test script

Tags: python, flask

I have a scrip in PHP that I use to test a simple loadbalancer web application. I put the file below in the web servers and it allow me to see if my LB is working.  I now need to write the same script in python using flask. I wonder if there is an equivalent of the following in python:

```
“<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo "Server IP: ".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
echo "\nClient IP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "\nX-Forwarded-for: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
echo "\n";
?>”
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To create simple flask application, just take a look at [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/).

`$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` - You must find some workaround. For example, you can store your IP in a config file.

> How would flask know the IP your webserver is listening on? I don't
>   think WSGI passes this information to the app.

https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1216

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` => `request.remote_addr`

`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` => `request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, This is the final script...

```
    from flask import Flask,request
    from prettytable import PrettyTable
    import os

    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        ipv4 = os.popen('ip addr show eth0').read().split("inet ")[1].split("/")[0]
        ipv6 = os.popen('ip addr show eth0').read().split("inet6 ")[1].split("/")[0]
        table = PrettyTable()
        table.field_names = ["IPv4", "IPv6", "REMOTE_ADDR", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
        table.add_row([ipv4, ipv6, request.remote_addr, request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")])
        return ('<pre>\n' + table.get_string() + '\n</pre>\n')
```